# Embed php code in custom field of a plugin

Tags: plugins, plugin-development

I am using this **plugin** https://wordpress.org/plugins/emailcoauthoronpost/ in my website. This plugin shoots an email to the author of the post with a link to my website. But I need to send the permalink of the post itself. So I need to embed some php code in the email body at the backend. Please see the snapshots.

**Current Version**
[image]

**My Requirement**

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the [Other Notes](https://wordpress.org/plugins/emailcoauthoronpost/other_notes/) of the plugin, you can use one of the variables to insert the post url.

> `$post_url` - Replaced with the URL of the post which was published

**Edit:**

You would just add the `$post_url` variable within your body field.

`<a href="$post_url">$title</a>`

Comment: Hey, thanks Greg...but how do I use it in Email body field ? Its a php variable...I think if just write <a href = "<?php echo $post_url ?>"> Post Link </a> in the Email Body field its not gonna work...what to do you think @Greg ?

Comment: @SaifMdTowfiqIslam - Updated the answer to show the example. It's doing a `str_replace('$post_url', get_permalink(), $body);` to swap it for the permalink.

Comment: yeah..should work...I will test it and then get back to you...thanks anyway...cheers man

Comment: If this worked for you, make sure to close the question by accepting an answer.

Comment: yeah, sure...i asked my customer to test it..i will update you as soon as i get the feedback..no worries man..cheers